# Sorting NSMutableArray by date

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

I want to sort a mutable array by date. My array contains several dict with keys say:key1,key2,birthday.Now, I have to sort by its birthday key:
I know that this can be done using:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"birthday" ascending:YES]; 
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

But my problem is that I want to sort only those arrays, which don’t contain empty birthday field. My array will contains several empty birthday fields. I don’t want to sort those.
Finally I have to load these in table view through `[self.mTable reloadData];`.

Comment: Define "I don't want to sort those". You want them in the end of the list? Or in the places they were before the sort?

Comment: They will be in the array but in table view, they should not be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First collect the indices of all objetcs without a birthday.

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSet];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    if(![[dict allKeys] containsObject:@"birthday"]){
        [indexSet addIndex:idx];
    }
}];
```

Now remove them from the original array

```
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];
```

Using a [comparator block](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html), sorting could look like

```
[array sortUsingComparator: ^(NSDictionary *d1, NSDictionary *d2) {    
    NSDate *date1 = [d1 objectForKey:@"birthday"];
    NSDate *date2 = [d2 objectForKey:@"birthday"];

    return [date1 compare:date2]
}
```

Comment: But this will also list out those in which birthday field is nil. I don’t want to show these fields

Comment: so filter before or after sorting sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different array to back your table view like this:

```
NSDictionary* obj1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSDate date] forKey: @"birthday"];
NSDictionary* obj2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: 0] forKey: @"birthday"];
NSDictionary* obj3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"wow" forKey: @"no_birthday"];

NSArray* all = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];
NSArray* onlyWithBirthday = [all valueForKeyPath: @"@unionOfObjects.birthday"];
```

And if you need the full objects for the table view, continue with this code:

```
NSPredicate* filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF.birthday IN %@", onlyWithBirthday];
NSArray* datasource = [all filteredArrayUsingPredicate: filter];
```

Then you can apply your sort method of choice.